# dynamic spring form:select element not bound to model

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, fragment

I am using Spring.AjaxEventDecoration to dynamically populate a drop down on my JSP but it is throwing an error as it cannot bind to the original model. I have been researching this for a while and I do not think this is possible but it seeems like it should be hence this post.. Help me out somebody!

OK My controller dumbed down looks like this,

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping(value = "/cis/crimeProperty/")
public class CrimePropertyController
{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/manageView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView managePropertyDetails(Long propertyId) throws DAOException
  {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    CrimePropertyVO crimePropertyVO = new CrimePropertyVO();
    model.put("crimePropertyVO", crimePropertyVO);
    return new ModelAndView("cis.crime.property.edit", model);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/changeItemList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView retrieveItemList(String propertyClass)
  {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ..call service to get list of items from class..
    model.put("propertyItemList", propertyItemList);
    return new ModelAndView("/cis/property/crime_property_item", model);
  }
}
```

I am using tiles so my tile definition looks like this,

```
<definition name="cis.crime.property.edit" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/cis/property/manage_crime_property.jsp">
<put-attribute name="itemListFrag" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/cis/property/crime_property_item.jsp"/>
```

My (manage_crime_property.jsp) JSP looks like so,

```
<form id= "changeList" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/smvc/cis/crimeProperty/changeItemList" method="post">  
<select id="propertyClassChange" path="propertyClass">
  <option value="" label="-Please Select-"/>
  <option value="CLO" label="CLOTHING"/>
  <option value="TOL" label="TOOLS"/>
</select>
</form
<form:form modelAttribute="crimePropertyVO" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/smvc/cis/crimeProperty/saveProperty" method="post">
  <table class="genericOutlinedTable" style="width: 100%;">

<tr>
  <td><b>Item</b></td>
  <td>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="itemListFrag" flush="true" ignore="false"/>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><b>Make</b></td>
  <td><form:input path="propertyMake" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
  <td><b>Model</b></td>
  <td><form:input path="propertyModel" size="15" maxlength="15"/></td>
</tr>
</form:form>     

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
    elementId:'propertyClassChange',
    event:'onchange',
    formId:'changeList',
    params: {fragments: 'itemListFrag'}
  }));

```
My (crime_property_item.jsp) JSP fragment looks like this,

<span id="itemListFrag">
  <form:select path="propertyItem">
    <form:option value="" label="-Please Select-">
<c:forEach var="itemList" items="${propertyItemList}">
  <form:option value="${itemList.propertyCode}" label="${itemList.propertyCode}" />  
</c:forEach>  
  </form:select>
</span>
```

Its all configured correctly and when I change the first drop down it calls my controller changeItemList method which returns my JSP frag and list of items to make up the options but I get a server error ...
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name propertyItemavailable as request attribute
I've tried having just the options tags in my frag but that doesn't work and I've tried using the spring:bind tag and normal select but can't get that to work either.

Many Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: ..call service to get list of items from class..
 does that item include a property "propertyItemavailable" ?

Comment: All that part means is that given the propertyClass param which is a string submitted to the method call a service which queries the database to return a list of items based on that propertyClass.

Comment: @tereško did you solved this? I am stuck on very similliar issue...